# Data wont show in COMBOBOXes after clicking data in datagridview. VBNET

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I have form that has `DataGridView` and three `ComboBox` controls. In datagrid, there's three columns. Now, when I click the datagridview(CellClick Event), the data I clicked should be display on combobox. But when I do, the other data doesnt show up. Only one was able to display the clicked cell in datagridview.
Here's my codes.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        ComboBox1.Text = row.Cells("GRADE LEVEL").Value
        cbSubject.Text = row.Cells("SUBJECT").Value
        cbTeacher.Text = row.Cells("TEACHER").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there any other codes to replace this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How are you populating the combo boxes? Where do the values come from originally and are you sure that the values you are setting in your `DataGridView1_CellClick` event exist in the combo boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ??
I don't really understand the question though, forgive me if I misunderstand :)

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DataSource = DataGridView1.DataSource
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "GRADE LEVEL"  'Column name as string here
            cbSubject.DataSource = DataGridView1.DataSource
            cbSubject.DisplayMember = "SUBJECT"
            cbTeacher.DataSource = DataGridView1.DataSource
            cbTeacher.DisplayMember = "TEACHER"
        Else 'clear the combo box
            ComboBox1.DataSource = Nothing 
            cbSubject.DataSource = Nothing
            cbTeacher.DataSource = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub
```

and you might want to add this code to select the whole row from datagridview when clicked

```
DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
```

you can put it in form load or sub new